# Display of umlauts inside Facebook

Tags: share, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, diacritics

I own several blogs and wondering about an umlauts problem, which appears at two of my blogs:

Umlauts and other special characters are not displayed correctly by share or link inside Facebook. I tryed to play around with og:description and others, but it did not help at all. I'm a bit confused, because I use the same template (source sructure) but get different facebook behavior.

Some examples:

- Working Snippet with correct umlauts: [www.elcario.de/7-erkenntnisse-von-der-seokomm-2011/2073/](http://www.elcario.de/7-erkenntnisse-von-der-seokomm-2011/2073/)
- Not working umlauts: [www.seo-news.de/google-eastereggs/2731/](http://www.seo-news.de/google-eastereggs/2731/)
- Also not working:
  www.tatort-news.com/schwarze-tiger-weisse-loewen-tatort-hannover-folge-820/2000/

Anyone of you has a clue why it's not working and how to fix it? I guess its a parsing issue of fb.

UPDATE: The Problem is the facebook cash: by fighting encoding probs you should better check uncached urls to see your changes or use the debug tool to renew the cash.
SOLVED